# PrimeVue - is there any way to hide the row selection column in the DataTable component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, primevue

I'm looking for a way to conditionally hide the row selection column in the DataTable component, for example I want to render it if I have a certain prop passed:

```
<DataTable>
  <Column v-if="propName == true" :selectionMode="selectedMode" headerStyle="width: 3em"></Column>
</DataTable>
```

However, when I try to do the above my table randomly renders 4 empty columns instead.

[screenshot of what I want to conditionally hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hmIL.png)

[what happens when I try to do use the v-if directive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVumS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to fix it using CSS styling to conditionally hide the column I want.

```
:style="useRowEditing === false ? 'display: none;' : ''"
```

Just added this to the column and passed an additional property to the column in my arrays.